# Resort datagridview after deleting data in datagridview for VB

Tags: vb.net, sorting, datagridview

I have a problem here regarding resorting numbers in datagridview.
I have a delete function as below:

```
  Dim pw As String
        pw = InputBox("Enter your password to delete data:", "Deleting Data", , ,)
    If UCase(pw) = "4034ML" Then
        Try
            Me.MasterlistBindingSource1.RemoveCurrent()
            Me.Validate()
            Me.MasterlistBindingSource1.EndEdit()
            Me.TableAdapterManager1.UpdateAll(Me.OrsaDataSet)
            MsgBox("Deleted Sucessfully!")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    Else
        MsgBox("Wrong Password")
    End If
```

However, after delete, the number sorting are not changed. If I delete cell number 3, the next cell will stay 4 not 3.

How to resort it back?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

after delete success reload your datagrid end of the  try block

Comment: How to do this?